# Checking previous rows to see if value exists

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The dataset has several rows for each customer ID, along with TS.

For each Customer ID, I want to check the `Status` column to check if it ever held `Cancelled` value in any of that Customer ID's previous rows. (ordered by TS)

| CustomerID | Status | TS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vimes | CANCELLED | Jan 1 |
| Vimes | ACTIVE | Jan 2 |
| Vimes | CANCELLED | Jan 3 |
| Sybill | ACTIVE | Jan 2 |
| Sybill | ACTIVE | Jan 5 |
| Sybill | ACTIVE | Jan 6 |

The result set should look like this, an added column with the flag `Rejoiner` which checks for previous values of the `Status` column -

| CustomerID | Status | TS | Rejoiner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vimes | CANCELLED | Jan 1 | No |
| Vimes | ACTIVE | Jan 2 | Yes |
| Vimes | CANCELLED | Jan 3 | Yes |
| Sybill | ACTIVE | Jan 2 | No |
| Sybill | ACTIVE | Jan 5 | No |
| Sybill | CANCELLED | Jan 6 | No |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select *, 
  if(countif(status = 'CANCELLED') over win > 0, 'Yes', 'No') as Rejoiner
from your_table 
window win as (partition by customerid order by unix_date(date(ts)) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]